# Simulation data from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, simulation

I have a question about simulating data with multivariate normal distribution. I want to generate data for a binary classification problem. Can I generate a subset A with parameters *mi_a* and *sigma_a* and assign it class 1, next generate a subset B with parameters *mi_b* and *sigma_b*=*sigma_a* and assign it class 2. And then combine these subsets into one set?

It's okay?  Do I have to do it in a different way, such as using marginal distributions?

Comment: A multivariate normal distribution will often involve non-zero covariances

Comment: That's fine. You can create toy datasets however you want. Out of curiosity, what's your purpose for generating this data?

Comment: Do you have a covariance matrix? If you don't, what you do is fine. Otherwise you have to use something like Cholesky or spectral decomposition, to apply the proper correlations.

Comment: I analyze different methods of classification of unbalanced data. And I want to compare these methods on real and synthetic data to consider different scenarios (class separation, noise, size etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: @Mami I take back my earlier comment -- if the goal is to compare the performances of various classification algorithms, then I think this way of generating is probably not good enough. I wouldn't expect it to reveal much about how various classification algorithms will perform on real datasets. Reviewers might not be satisfied. I'd look at how recent machine learning papers on this topic test their algorithms (if they use synthetic data, how do they generate it) and do something similar to that.